# Execute remote commands, completely detaching from the ssh connection

Tags: ssh, scripting, nohup, background-process

I have 2 computers, `localpc` and `remoteserver`.

I need `localpc` to execute some commands on `remoteserver`. One of the things it needs to do is start a backup script that runs for a number of hours. I would like the command on `localpc` to “fire” and then be running totally independent on `remoteserver`, like `localpc` was never there in the first place.

This is what I have done so far:

`remoteserver` contains has the script:

```
/root/backup.sh
```

`localpc` is scheduled to run this:

```
ssh root@remoteserver 'nohup /root/backup.sh' &
```

Am I doing this the right way? Is there a better way to do this? Will I run into any trouble doing it this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996089/use-ssh-to-start-a-background-process-on-a-remote-server-and-exit-session and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine provide a number of useful approaches for this problem not using screen/tmux etc...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should probably use `screen` on the remote host, to have a real detached command:

```
ssh root@remoteserver screen -d -m ./script
```

Comment: I like this idea. When the script finishes, screen will still be running through... and I'd have to somehow reconnect to it next time I wanted to run it, right?

Comment: @AaronJAnderson: no, given that the command is not a shell, when it terminates also that screen session terminates.

Answer (score 64):

Close, but not exactly.

#### Independently of any terminal

```
ssh root@remoteserver '/root/backup.sh </dev/null >/var/log/root-backup.log 2>&1 &'
```

You need to close all file descriptors that are connected to the ssh socket, because the ssh session won't close as long as some remote process has the socket open. If you aren't interested in the script's output (presumably because the script itself takes care of writing to a log file), redirect it to `/dev/null` (but note that this will hide errors such as not being able to start the script).

Using `nohup` has no useful effect here. `nohup` arranges for the program it runs not to receive a HUP signal if the program's controlling terminal disappears, but here there is no terminal in the first place, so nothing is going to send a SIGHUP to the process out of the blue. Also, `nohup` redirects standard output and standard error (but not standard input) to a file, but only if they're connected to a terminal, which, again, they aren't.

#### Detaching from a terminal

```
 aaron@localpc$ ssh root@remoteserver
 root@remoteserver# nohup /root/backup.sh </dev/null &
 nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
 [1] 12345
 root@remoteserver# exit
 aaron@localpc$
```

Use `nohup` to detach the script from its controlling terminal so that it doesn't receive a [SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) when the terminal disappears. `nohup` also redirects the script's standard output and standard error to a file called `nohup.out`if they're connected to the terminal; you have to take care of standard input yourself.

#### Keeping a remote terminal

If you want to keep the command running in a remote terminal but not have it attached to the SSH session, run it in a terminal multiplexer such as [Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [Tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux).

```
ssh root@remoteserver 'screen -S backup -d -m /root/backup.sh'
```

You can later reconnect to the terminal where the script is running by invoking `screen -S backup -rd` as root on that machine.

#### Automating one remote command

For slightly better security, don't open direct remote root logins too widely. Create a special-purpose key pair and give it a forced command in [`/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8&format=html#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT). The contents of the public key file is `AAAA…== wibble@example.com`; add a comma-separated list of options including `command="…"` which specifies that the key can only be used to execute this specific command. Be sure to keep the options and the key all on one line.

```
command="/root/backup.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-x11-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc AAAA…== wibble@example.com
```

Comment: I have tried the first command you listed. It does not background on the box that executed the command. The cursor just sits there and waits for completion... perhaps it's a bug?

Comment: You might need to redirect stdin to /dev/null on the remote system.   That may be why ssh isn't exiting.

Comment: I would add the `-f` option to get ssh to ‘background’ (i.e. terminate, close connections) on the local side. This will work in conjunction with the `&`. `nohup` is optional in this case, but you might consider using `setsid` instead.

Comment: @KeithB Redirecting stdin is part of it, but I also need to redirect stdout and stderr: nohup won't do it here because they're not terminals, and in fact nohup isn't useful here.

Comment: @Alexios Using `-f` is not useful unless a terminal is needed for authentication, and I'm not going to recommend that. With `ssh -f`, the ssh client is detached from the terminal on `localpc`, but it keeps running in the background for no useful purpose.

Comment: @Gilles That's very true. Just hedging bets. I'm too busy to check the SSH source code, but will the remote daemon exit if the process has forked, detached from all open FDs and/or spawned a new SID? Scratch that, of course it should. For all intents and purposes, it would be done processing its ‘session’.

Comment: While all else might be correct, as far as I know ssh connections build virtual terminals on both client and host. So saying that there is no terminal is incorrect, there are two. But it might still be true that nothing sends a hup

Comment: @erikb85 An ssh connection doesn't create a virtual terminal on the client side (why would it?), and creates a terminal on the sever side only with the `-t` option or if no command is passed.

Comment: @Gilles Well I'm no expert, but people who program on the tty level told me so. Additional evidence points in the same direction: a) `stty -echo` works b) My man page reads `If a pseudo-terminal has been allocated (normal login session)[...]`

Comment: @erikb85 That pseudo-terminal is on the server side, not on the client side.

Comment: @Gilles And that does or does not send a SIGHUP when it closes? I'd be really curious about how this works and where to get such kind of information. Such kind of low level topics often does not yield many google results, at least the way I google.

Comment: @erikb85 I don't understand your question: send SIGHUP to what? The processes on the server get a SIGHUP when the connection goes down, because the terminal goes away at that point (the sshd process that manages the server side of the connection exits when the connection is severed). There are several threads about the intricacies of SIGHUP, shell jobs and process groups on this site.

Comment: @Gilles Your answer that we are currently commenting on says you don't need `nohup` because your shell command does not receive any SIGHUPs. But now we find through discussion that sshd creates a pseudo terminal for the shell command. And if I understand you correctly closing the connection will result in the command receiving a SIGHUP from the closing pseudo terminal. That means `nohup` might still have a reason to be used.

Comment: @erikbwork Please note that I have absolutely no clue about those things, but following the discussion and the comments: Gilles does not use the -t option in his commands, so no pseudo terminal will be established, neither at the client nor at the server side. Therefore, no HUP will be sent.

Answer (score 13):

The standard recipe for running a remote command from a remote login like SSH is the following:

```
nohup command </dev/null >command.log 2>&1 &
```

If `command` is a shell script that takes care of logging to a file itself, then you could change `command.log` to `/dev/null`. Once you start this, log off right away.

You need everything on that line.

`nohup` tells the shell not to disturb the process if the login session is disconnected.

`</dev/null` tells it never to wait for input

`>command.log` tells it to send any messages to this named log file

`2>&1` tells it to send any stderr messages to the same log file. In some cases it is better to have two files, the second one to collect error messages, and the first to collect normal activity messages. That can make it easier to verify that everything worked correctly.

`&` tells it to detach this process and run it in the background as a daemon process.

Answer (score 13):

This thread was very helpful but my solution had to be a bit different.

I don't like the screen solution because it leaves a screen process running which I don't need.
The redirections and nohups used like this:

```
ssh root@remoteserver '/root/backup.sh </dev/null >/var/log/root-backup.log 2>&1 &'
```

were NOT working for me when used with the ssh command.

I created a wrapper script on the remote machine which runs the actual script. The wrapper script sets the redirection and nohup. Something like this:

```
backupwrapper.sh:
nohup backup.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Then on my client machine I run (notice no redirection):

```
# ssh remotemachine "backupwrapper.sh"
#
```

The ssh command immediately returns, the connection is terminated and the script is left running.

Answer (score 7):

As [Nils says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30415/34409), it's a security risk to allow root to log in via ssh. And I advise against running any substantial job on a machine without a log. If anything goes wrong, you'll wish you had some troubleshooting messages. There are other answers showing you how to do that. But here's how I recommend accomplishing just what you asked for. It's all built into sh(1). No need for GNU screen (although I think that's a clever solution). Append this string to your command: `>&- 2>&- <&- &`. `>&-` means close stdout. `2>&-` means close stderr. `<&-` means close stdin. `&` means run in the background, e.g.

```
$ ssh myhost 'sleep 30 >&- 2>&- <&- &'
# ssh returns right away, and your sleep job is running remotely
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You should background the remote command on `remoteserver`. The way you do it will background the ssh-command on `localpc`.

Apart from that it is a bad idea to allow root-ssh.

So setup on `remoteserver`: A sudoers line that will run `/root/backup.sh` as root by user `backup`.

You could create that user without "good" password.

Put the command `sudo /root/backup.sh &` as command into `~backup/.ssh/authorized_keys` — together with the public key from `localpc` (whoever triggers that script).

Answer (score -1):

```
#screen -d -m -S BACKUP ssh root@remoteserver /root/backup.sh
```

Comment: That's not very useful: if the SSH connection dies, the script's stdout and stderr will be closed, which may cause trouble. Screen should be running on the remote machine (as in [enzotib's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30400/execute-remote-commands-completely-detaching-from-the-ssh-connection/30507#30507)).