# Let Transmission running on the server, independently of SSH session

Tags: ssh, transmission

This question has been reworded, previous one was a duplicate of [Execute remote commands, completely detaching from the ssh connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30400/execute-remote-commands-completely-detaching-from-the-ssh-connection)

I want to access to a computer through SSH, run both Iceweasel and Transmission, use Iceweasel to find some torrents, add the torrents to Transmission, close Icewasel, close my SSH session and let Transmission running on the server.

I'm running Transmission using `nohup`, but if I close Transmission, it closes on the server. If I exit the session, it closes as well.

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but `transmission` has a dual mode in which you can run it as a daemon, then use a commandline interface or `transgui` to manage its torrents.

Comment: @Shadur I have it already configured using the daemon and local web gui

Answer (score 0):

You can try `nohup` ("no hangup").  For example:

```
nohup myapp &
```

If that's not enough, redirect all the I/O streams:

```
nohup myapp < /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

By default nohup has already redirected stream 1 to "nohup.out", but you can change that (see `man nohup`).  Wikipedia also has a [good article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Notice that you still need to use `&` with nohup.