# Starting job via SSH and detaching from a composite command

Tags: bash, ssh, io-redirection

I'd like to start a long running script via SSH and immediately return. Afterwards, I want to check the remote host every 5 minutes to see if the job is done.

In order to accomplish the first part, I used [this trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30433/18037):

```
ssh root@remoteserver 'TMP_FILE=$(mktemp --tmpdir backup.XXXXXXXXXX.log) && (/root/backup.sh </dev/null > $TMP_FILE 2>&1 &) && echo $TMP_FILE'
```

Now, for the second part, since backup.sh can be any script, I'd like to append something like `DONE_$TMP_FILE` to the file pointed to by `$TMP_FILE` when backup.sh terminates and, every 5 minutes, run this command:

```
ssh root@remoteserver 'tail -1 $TMP_FILE'
```

to see if the last line is equal to `DONE_$TMP_FILE`.

The problem is that I can't manage to detach from a composite command:

```
ssh root@remoteserver 'TMP_FILE=$(mktemp --tmpdir backup.XXXXXXXXXX.log) && (/root/backup.sh </dev/null > $TMP_FILE 2>&1 && echo DONE_$TMP_FILE >> $TMP_FILE &) && echo $TMP_FILE'
```

The above command will simply block until `backup.sh` finishes running.

Is there any way to detach from a sequence of commands without placing them in a wrapper shell script?

If there is any better way of doing this, I'd love to hear it. Ideally, I shouldn't need to create any auxiliary shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution is easier than I thought:

```
ssh root@remoteserver 'TMP_FILE=$(mktemp --tmpdir backup.XXXXXXXXXX.log) && ((/root/backup.sh && echo DONE_$TMP_FILE) </dev/null > $TMP_FILE 2>&1 &) && echo $TMP_FILE'
```